# SQL Pivot with unbalanced data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, aggregate

I'm deeling with the Pivot function if it is possible to "fill up" data not included in the main table.
My table includes these data:

```
create table tmpData (objID INT, colID varchar(5), value varchar(50));
insert into tmpData (objId, colId, value) values(21, 'col1', 'a value');
insert into tmpData (objId, colId, value) values(21, 'col2', 'col2_1');
insert into tmpData (objId, colId, value) values(21, 'col2', 'col2_2_x'); -- a second 'value' for col_2
insert into tmpData (objId, colId, value) values(21, 'col3', 'col3_1');
insert into tmpData (objId, colId, value) values(22, 'col1', 'another value');
insert into tmpData (objId, colId, value) values(22, 'col2', 'col2_2');
insert into tmpData (objId, colId, value) values(22, 'col3', 'col3_2');
```

With the Pivot function

```
select
*
from (
select
  objID
, colID
, value
from tmpData)
 t
PIVOT (MAX(value) for colID in ([col1], [col2], [col3])) pivottable;
```

I get only one (max) value for objID=21 in col2:

```
objID col1          col2         col3
21   a value        col2_2_x     col3_1
22   another value  col2_2       col3_2
```

What I like to get is all values AND filled up the non given data for objID=21 in col1 and col3:

```
objID col1          col2        col3
21    a value       col2_2      col3_1
21    a value       col2_2_x    col3_1
22    another value col2_2      col3_2
```

Is this possible with the Pivot function or in another way?
Many thanks in advance
  Joerg

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The syntax looks like SQL Server.

Comment: at the end is has to work for SQL Server and ORACLE

Answer (score 0):

You seem to (sort of) want lists in the columns.  If you can live with this result:

```
objID col1          col2        col3
21    a value       col2_2      col3_1
21    NULL          col2_2_x    NULL
22    another value col2_2      col3_2
```

Then you can do this by enumerating the values:

```
select objId,
       max(case when colId = 'col1' then value end) as col1,
       max(case when colId = 'col2' then value end) as col2,
       max(case when colId = 'col3' then value end) as col3
from (select d.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by objId, colId order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from tmpData d.*
     ) t
group by objId, seqnum;
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do what you want by using cumulative `max()`:

```
select objId,
       max(max(case when colId = 'col1' then value end)) over (partition by objId order by seqnum) as col1,
       max(max(case when colId = 'col2' then value end)) over (partition by objId order by seqnum) as col2,
       max(max(case when colId = 'col3' then value end)) over (partition by objId order by seqnum) as col3
from (select d.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by objId, colId order by (select value)) as seqnum
      from tmpData d.*
     ) t
group by objId, seqnum;
```

Note that the `order by` in the `dense_rank()` has been changed to explicitly order by the value.

Comment: very quick answer. Thanks. The second SQL does the trick for ORACLE as well :-). Do you know a solution for SQL Server 2008?

Comment: I like to update this solution. The culmulative max() is working for ORACLE as well. But real life is more complex than the example above. In real life I have to deal with more than 100 columns, not only 3. In this case ORACLE ends up in  ORA-01467: sort key too long :-( But OK, once you do not have so many columns it is working fine.

Comment: @DickerXXL . . . Having to use 100 columns for a sort seems suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE and left join to get values from col1 and col3 for all col2 values

```
;with
t  as (select distinct objID    from #tmpData ),
t1 as (select objID, value col1 from #tmpData   where colID = 'col1'),
t2 as (select objID, value col2 from #tmpData   where colID = 'col2'),
t3 as (select objID, value col3 from #tmpData   where colID = 'col3')
select t.objID, col1, col2, col3
from t
left join t1 on t.objID = t1.objID
left join t2 on t.objID = t2.objID
left join t3 on t.objID = t3.objID
order by t.objID
```

this will work also if you have more values for col1 or col3

Comment: I like to update this solution. The "self join" is working for ORACLE as well. But real life is more complex than the example above. In real life I have to deal with more than 100 columns, not only 3. In this case ORACLE consumes > 100 GB of temp-tablespace and does not ends up in a result after hours :-( But OK, once you do not have so many columns it is working fine.

Comment: @DickerXXL can you give us the order of magnitude of records, of columns and distinct objID?